# iOS Detecting Whether Tab is Changed

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have tabbed iOS application. I need to know which tab is active and detect when tab is changed. In storyboard I have a tab view controller, which changes the view when you click a tab fine. I created a class `TabBarController` and it is defined as follows:

Header

```
@interface TabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "TabBarController.h"

@implementation TabBarController

// In the initialization section, set the delegate
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
    NSLog(@"controller title: %@", viewController.title);
}

@end
```

However, I couldn't detect tab changes with the code above. What do you think that the problem is?

I haven't linked my tab view to any outlets, but segues to other views. Is this the problem? Then, where should I link my outlet to?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Solution to this is the implementation viewDidLoad as follows:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"Tabs showed up!");
    self.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you confirmed that your `init` method is being called? I don't think `init` is the designated initializer for `UITabBarController` and may not be called when loading the controller from a nib/storyboard.

If that's the case you may find it easier to set the delegate in your `viewDidLoad` since that will be called regardless of how the object is initialized or else make sure you set the delegate when `-initWithNibName:bundle:` or `-initWithCoder` is used to instantiate the object.

Comment: Thanks @Jonah. I solved the problem via putting self.delegate = self; into viewDidLoad.